# VI how to replace the n character appearing after the first n characters in each line

Tags: linux, postgresql, vi

I have a data set delimited by commas as seen below.

882710454,122.00 
883710414,122.00 
888710514,122.00 
888,710,414,122.00

However, there're specific lines in the data set that have commas appearing after every 3 characters (check line 4 in the above) making it impossible to import the data to a postgres db. I would like to remove the commas appearing after every 3 characters and remain only with the comma that is the valid delimiter.

Please note that am dealing with a huge data set making it impossible to remove the commas line by line. i require a global command that can do this in vi or nano.

Please assist.

Comment: Are there only two fields or do you have to deal with cases like `12,123,123.00` that are in fact three fields and not twelve millions ? Because that's pretty tricky to do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use regex and global find and replace in vi:

```
:%s/,\(\d\{3}\),/\1/g
```

Explanation:

- `%s` is for search and replace
- `/` starts a search part
- `,\(\d\{3}\),` matches comma + three numbers + comma (`\` is en escape character)
- `/` ends a search part, starts a replace part
- `\1` matches three numbers from the search part
- `/` ends a replace part
- `g` is for global replace (in the whole file)

Answer (score 0):

vi:

```
:%s/^\([0-9]\{3\}\),\([0-9]\{3\}\),\([0-9]\{3\}\),/\1\2\3,/
```